# Interleaving components on an HTML page

Tags: angular

I am a newbie in Angular.

I have a big external component(imported from some external libraries) that renders an image and navigation links and the header component.

I created a new component and want to add in the section where the above component is being rendered.

How do I control positioning of the above component?

Answer (score 0):

Add the HTML selector of new component in the component where you want to load.

#### New Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home', \\this is the html selector
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
```

#### HTML

```
<app-home></app-home>  //add this in the old component HTML page
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.However the component thats being rendered is coming from some libraries and I dont want to alter the standard libraries from a framework.